# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1 requires a model item of type '.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pull all the USERS created in the database(AspNetUsers) using Register form.
I have read several similar issues but can't fix this issue.Usually the reason for this error is when we try to pull a list from the controller but in view we do not specify IEnumerable at top.However I have added that as well , please see the code  below. Million thanks for any help in advance.

```
@model IEnumerable<TimeSheet.ViewModel.UserViewModel>
@using TimeSheet.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Manage User</h2>
<br/>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tr class="table-header">
        
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email)
        </th>
       
        
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Email)
            </td>
            
            <td>
                @Html.Partial("_TableButtonPartial", new IndividualButtonPartial { UserId = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

UserController

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        TimeSheetEntities db = new TimeSheetEntities();
       /* private ApplicationDbContext db;
        public UserController()
        {
            db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
        }*/
        // GET: User
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.AspNetUsers.ToList());
            //return View();
        }
}
```

UserViewModel

```
namespace TimeSheet.ViewModel
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; } }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the exact type of `TimeSheetEntities.AspNetUsers`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please elaborate it bit more , How do we identify type or what do we mean by type? Please accept my apologies if it is a childish question but i have no idea.

Comment: When you use `db.AspNetUsers`, that's using the `AspNetUsers` property of the `TimeSheetEntities` class. What is the type of that property? How is it declared?

Comment: @JassSanghera Basically when you return `db.AspNetUsers` to your `View`, it should be of type: `TimeSheet.ViewModel.UserViewModel` and then you cast to a `List` which it is not doing and the error is thrown. Please check what type are you returning back to your `View` since it is expecting something which you are not sending correctly from the `Index` method.

Answer (score -1):

Since your are using mostly email,the easiest way to fix would be to change a model class

```
@model List<AspNetUser>
```

or if you want to save some network traffic, you can  go a long way

create this viewmodel

```
public class UserGridViewModel
{
   public string Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

fix the action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 var model= db.AspNetUsers.Select(i=> new  UserGridViewModel { 
  Id=i.Id,
  Email=i.Email
}).ToList();

  return View(model);
}
```

and view

```
@model List<TimeSheet.ViewModel.UserGridViewModel>
```